# How to deploy the wicket examples in Tomcat?

Tags: wicket

How do I deploy the Wicket examples in Tomcat?

In the maven repo I see the wicket-examples artifact. But I never deployed a war in this way. Or should I manually deploy the war in it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would download and deploy the [war](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/wicket/wicket-examples/6.18.0/) manually. (Or just grab the sources and compile them on your own).

Answer (score 0):

Just download the wicket-examples-x.y.z.war file and put it in TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/ folder renamed as we.war. Then navigate to `http://localhost:8080/we/`